# NSTextView delegate not working?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView where i put the delegate to my file owner. My file owner is then assosiated with a class where i do different stuff in the view.

To my understanding it should now be possible to catch events from the NSTextView inside my class (because i have set its delegate to file owner), but it does not seem to work, why is that?

I have implemented this function in my class:

```
- (BOOL)control: (NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector: (SEL)commandSelector {

    NSLog(@"i was fired!");

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTextViewDelegate

the method signature looks like:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)aSelector
```

give that a try instead.

Comment: hey thank you for the link, i din't know about that delegate :-)

Answer (score 1):

The selector is just `textView:doCommandBySelector:`; drop the `control`.